# Ask rails to not bundle javascript in production - 5.0.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

What's the best way to ask rails to not bundle my javascript in production?

I don't need this feature bad enough to deal with the headache involved.

Right now I've copied my development environment to production but I need an easy long term solution.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can move this gem from global to environment specific

```
group :development do
 gem 'jquery-rails'
end
```

In above mentioned case the gem will only be loaded in development environment.

Other workaround can be:

```
group :production do
 gem 'jquery-rails', require: false
end
```

Note: Above mentioned workaround, may incur other dependency conflict.